# Issue while using Constant Throughput timer in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, test-script

I have constant throughput timer which will hit 1 request in 3 minutes in my test plan due to this my requests are getting timeout as it is delaying requests to 1 hour. Please suggest what should be the workaround of it?

Answer (score 1):

In JMeter you can control the connect/response timeouts at the "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)) where you can increase the default timeouts to the desired values:

[image]

However I fail to see how Constant Throughput Timer is connected with the timeouts because it slows the number of requests per minute down, individual requests go at the full speed.